# Text for <a></a> tags does not show up in Internet Explorer (7-8) with a background-image defined

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, anchor

Alright,
  I feel dumb asking this but I am having issues with a stylized anchor tag and displaying both a repeating background image and text in IE7/8.  My code works fine in Firefox, IE9, Chrome, and Safari but in IE7/8 the text will not show up.

**My PHP is outputting something like this:**

```
<a class="anchorLink border-radius-5 anchorButton" href="#anchorPanel2">Would you like to know more?</a>
```

**My CSS for this element looks like this:**

```
.anchorButton {
    background-image: url("./images/button-gradient.png");
    height: 52px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-position: 0 0;
    float: left;
    line-height: 52px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #a8a8a8;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    z-index: 900;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #fff !important;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px #707070 !important;
    display: block;
}
```

To see what I am talking about you can visit: [dtelepathy.swampedpublishing.com](http://dtelepathy.swampedpublishing.com).  If you look at the site in Firefox and IE7/8 you will see that the Orange 'buttons' that I made out of anchor tags do not show the text in IE.

I am willing to give whatever a shot as I am REALLY unsure what is going on here.

Comment: You need to specify left:0 for your topbar. There are a lot of float:left items that don't need to be floated, and you're not clearing floats where they finish. There is a lot of superfluous z-index stuff as well. Not the cause of the link problem, but stuff to look out for anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I will clean that all up now that I got this issue fixed.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have IE7/8 to test, but this sounds suspiciously like a variation on the [IE peek-a-boo bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/peekaboo.html). Maybe some of the [changes suggested around the interwebs](http://www.brownbatterystudios.com/sixthings/2007/01/06/css-first-aid-for-ie-peekaboo-bug/) will help.

Comment: I will check it out.  I have tried searching the web with no luck so far.

Comment: Well, you were right.  I added `code`position: relative; /* peekaboo bug fix for IE6 */
min-width: 0; /* peekaboo bug fix for IE7 */`code` and this fixed the bug in IE6/7/8.  It looks like this bug does stil exist in IE8 and not just 7/6.

Comment: As to the IE8 appearance of the bug, is IE running in IE7 compatibility mode, or is the bug inherent to IE8 in standards mode?

Comment: David,  I tried using DOCTYPE switching to put IE8 in standards mode to no avail.  I am using the html5 <!DOCTYPE html> with Blueprint CSS and an html5 shiv for IE LT 9 (html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js). I am also using BrowserLab to view the IE files since I am on OSX so I will try and get on a windows box to confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

I've just written a guide for you. Make sure that you follow these steps, and -perhaps- edit your question to be more specific. Currently, we can only guess and find the problem by trial&error.

Steps to debug your CSS code (yes = next step, no = see below):

1. **Ensure that the problem is caused by CSS**
   Disable JavaScript. Does the problem persist?
2. **What's the source**
   Temporary disable all specific selectors, eg: `<a class="foo bar">` > `<a x-class="foo bar">`. Did the problem disappear?<sup>[2]</sup>
3. **Which selector?**
   Add all selectors, one by one. When a newly added selector is causing problems, disable all selectors, and use the same selector to make sure that the problem is caused by this selector only.
4. **Which property?**
   Disable all lines, and add enable a few lines (block) of the CSS code. When the problem shows up after re-adding a block, remove the just-added block, and add the properties back, one by one.
5. **Cause found**
   Use Google, Stack overflow or the [Mozilla Developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/) to find documentation about the property. Perhaps, you've used the property in a wrong way.

<sup>[2]</sup> The problem is caused by a tag selector, or an inherited style.

Comment: I tried going through all of that and did not manage to find a solution.  I spent a few days on this.  Next time I will be more clear on the steps I have already taken to fix the issue.

Comment: I've noticed that you're using lots of `margin` and `padding` to position your page. However, you're also using `float` (and `position:fixed`). `float` rips an element from his context. Non-standard compliant browsers (such as IE) tend to be bad at correctly dealing with this "complex" situation.

Comment: Rob, I originally designed the site using all position: absolute.  This turned out to be a terrible idea though as I could not get it to work in IE.  The only fixed element should be the topbar and everything else should be a part of a float now.  If there is a better way or a good reference for up-to-date coding standards I would love to see it.  Bad code like this happens when you let hardware folks have a low barrier to entry by giving us interpreted coding languages.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the text in the orange buttons just fine in IE8 on Win7.

Your hover for the border color doesn't work on them though in IE8, but that is because of the VML used for the rounded corner effect. I have experimented a lot with VML and it causes tons of problems for element layouts.

I would check to see if removing the **border-radius-5** class fixes the problem. That way you can see if that is causing the text problem you are seeing.